# Switching between compiler directives in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, compiler-directives

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with SDK based project, with multiple targets:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45;net46</TargetFrameworks>
```

[image]

But when I write conditional code, I see (obviously) some code in gray and some code in regular colors :

[image]

**Question:**

What settings decide which section will be gray and which will not?
Because now, if I want to edit the "`NETFULL`" section (because I'm multitargeting), it's all gray and I don't have intellisense.

How can I tell VS: now let's switch to `NETFULL` mode?

NB 
Sure I can remove the condition but I want to know why is it gray and how can I switch between them ( since I'm multitargeting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To switch between the frameworks you are targeting use the dropdown at the top left of the code pane:

[image]
[image]

---

Conditional-compilation symbols are declared in the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net46'">
  <DefineConstants>NETFULL</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or you can use the [predefined symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031308/397817) such as `NETFRAMEWORK`, `NETSTANDARD` or `NETCOREAPP` (or the versioned predefined symbols such as `NETSTANDARD2_0`).

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of conditional compilation symblols which you define in properites of your project.

Navigate to proprties tab of your project and select Build tab. There you can define those symobls.

[image]

Comment: But (regardless to define) - how does it know which section to show  ? this dll can be called from net core or net fw. BTW , now I see that I missed the `defineConstant`section {search for "netfull" [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/22/multitargeting-and-porting-a-net-library-to-net-core-20))}. But even If I define those , how does it know the targetFramework ? it's only at runtime. becuase  like i said , a console app ( dotnet core ) app can call this dll , and also 4.5

Comment: Well, you define your own configuration, or use debug configuration. Then just specify additional symbols, like I did in example. Then when you switch to defined configuration (in my case Debug (no hardware)), code under `#if Additional_Symbol` is active, gets compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Redefine TargetFrameworks. Use the same syntax, just put in the other targets.