# Are there any formalized target framework directives?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard, compiler-directives

I've read [Microsoft's article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) about how to detect target framework, for example :

```
netcoreapp2.2
net47
net58
```

But there are situations where I don't care about the *exact* version, but the general framework target :

```
NETCORE
.Net Framework
```

But I didn't find such flags.

**Question:**

Are there any generalized flags for that ? or better, how can I distinguish between those two without specifying all options?

Comment: What's your use case? If you're talking about a library, you can target The Net Standard version that covers all the platforms you need.

Comment: For example: `Server.Mappath` doesn't exist in standard nor core. Only on FW. I need to know am I going to get a file for a specific file. ( that's one example, there are more).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the version-specific directives such as `NETSTANDARD2_0`, the [Target frameworks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks) lists the following preprocessor symbols:

- `NETFRAMEWORK`
- `NETSTANDARD`
- `NETCOREAPP`

...and `NETMF` for .NET Micro Framework, `WP` for Windows Phone, and `UAP` for Universal Windows Platform.

---

Here is an example `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>   
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.5;netstandard2.0;net48;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and C# class:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
#if NETFRAMEWORK
            System.Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework");
#elif NETCOREAPP
            System.Console.WriteLine(".NET Core");
#elif NETSTANDARD
            System.Console.WriteLine(".NET Standard");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Here's .NET Core 3.0 selected (see top left), with the `NETCOREAPP` region 'live' and the others greyed out:

[image]