# Is there an OR operator in C# conditional compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, conditional-compilation

I am currently building a .NET assembly that should work in .NET 4.5 and at least two .NET Core versions (.NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 3.0).

I am using conditional compilation like so:

```
#if NET45
        //Use as System.Web.HttpContext
        isHttps = context.Request.IsSecureConnection;
        IPAddress fromIp = IPAddress.Parse(context.Request.UserHostAddress);
        string path = context.Request.Path;
#elif NETCOREAPP2_1
        //Use as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
        isHttps = context.Request.IsHttps;
        IPAddress fromIp = context.Request.HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        string path = context.Request.Path;
#elif NETCOREAPP3_0
        //Use as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
        isHttps = context.Request.IsHttps;
        IPAddress fromIp = context.Request.HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        string path = context.Request.Path;
#endif
```

Since the code for NETCOREAPP2_1 and NETCOREAPP3_0 is the same I wonder wheter I could use something like:

```
#if NET45
        //...
#elif NETCOREAPP2_1 [OR] NETCOREAPP3_0
        //...
#endif
```

However, this syntax does not work.

**Is there valid syntax to have an OR operator in conditional compilation like this?**

Note: Since this involves the ASP.NET request pipeline, I guess .NET Standard is not an option. You may want to have a look at the code in time: https://github.com/suterma/SqlSyringe/blob/f7df15e2c40a591b8cea24389a1ba8282eb02f6c/SqlSyringe/Syringe.cs

Comment: Yes. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: As you are targeting 2 versions of .NET Core and want _the same code for both of them_ you could simplify this to `#elif NETCOREAPP` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031308/397817

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is. It's the same as in a standard `if`:

```cs
#if NET45
    // ...
#elif (NETCOREAPP2_1 || NETCOREAPP3_0)
    // ...
#endif
```

More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if